# Can anyone explain why the return value is NaN first example? The the second example is fine

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why the return value is NaN first example? The the second example is fine.

ex: 1

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++);
  return b[i] *= a;
}
```

ex: 2

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++)
    b[i] *= a;
  return b;
}
console.log(mul(2,1,1,1));
```

Comment: @David - When did JavaScript got block-based scope?

Comment: `i` is not outside of _scope_, it is outside of _range_. Once your return statement is processed the value of `i` is 3, and `b[3]` is `NaN`

Comment: @PM77-1: Good point.  I just learned something new about JavaScript.  Though I'll likely still keep the scope intuitively block-based in my code, just to keep the code clear :)

Comment: A little bit of formatting might help, brackets would help more.

Comment: @PM77-1—ECMAScript has had block scope since [*let*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) was introduced with edition 6 (aka ECMASCript 2015).

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Because `b[i]` is `undefined` in the first example.

Let's say you're looping over an array of length 3.  In the loop the index `i` covers: 0, 1, 2

However, after the last iteration of the loop, `i` has been incremented again and is now `3`.  When you try to access `b[3]` if `b` is of length 3 then it's undefined.  And using undefined in a math operation produces `NaN`.

```
for (var i=0;i<b.length;i++); // i loops from 0 to the length of the array
return b[i]*=a; // i is now outside the bounds of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this code and observe its results.

```js
mul(2, 1, 2);

function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0;i<b.length;i++);
  alert(i);
  alert(b[i]);
  return b[i]*=a;
}
```

After the loop ends `i` equals `b.length`. By using `b[i]` you extend your original array.

You did not assign `b[i]` a numeric value prior to using it. Hence the result.

Comment: It's much more user friendly to use *console.log* rather than *alert*.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what is happening because there is a semicolon in the first example that isn't in the second.

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++); <=== this one
  return b[i] *= a;
}
```

The semicolon immediately after the bracket closing the *for* statement is effectively an empty block, so the loop runs to completion without doing anything. Equivalent code is:

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    // empty block
  }
  return b[i] *= a;
}
```

On the next line, *i* has been incremented to *b.length* (i.e. 3) so `b[3]` returns undefined.

In the second example, the semicolon is missing, so the following statement is effectively wrapped in brackets to be a block. That statement is looped over 3 times (from 0 to 2 inclusive) and ends with *i* as 3 (just like above):

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++)  <=== no semicolon
    b[i] *= a;                    <=== so this statement is the block
  return b;
}
```

Equivalent code is:

```
function mul(a,...b){
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    b[i] *= a;
  }
  return b;
}
```